# Multiple RollingFileAppenders writing to same file

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, slf4j, logback

I have two contexts running in the same JVM and Tomcat instance, and I'd like to write to the same logging file using the logback RollingFileAppender. Is the logback RollingFileAppender synchronized to prevent any issues if I use the same file?  I am concerned the rolling over of the files would not work correctly, as well as some logs getting overridden.

The logback docs [mention a prudent mode](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudentWithRolling), but this indicates a performance hit and only refers to logging to the same file from different JVMs. I will be running in the same JVM.

Here is an example of my logback.xml.  I would like to have this in two separate WAR files for each context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/portal.log</file>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>portal.%d.log</fileNamePattern>
    <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
      </triggeringPolicy>  
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source shows that the doAppend() method is synchronized.  A comment in the rollover() method says it does not need to by synchronized since doAppend() is.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/0.9.3/ch/qos/logback/core/AppenderBase.java#AppenderBase.doAppend%28java.lang.Object%29

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/0.9.3/ch/qos/logback/core/AppenderBase.java#AppenderBase.doAppend%28java.lang.Object%29

You could still run into issues, though.

Comment: This is true. I am wondering if anyone has used the RollingFileAppender in this manner or if it is documented somewhere that I might have just not seen.

Answer (score 0):

I am using RollingFileAppender in this manner and face the same issues as you. It only seems to work if you remove the `<file>` element from your configuration. But then, all files are named e.g. `portal.2013-12-03.log` and so on. If you can live with that, there you go.

Still, I need a constant file name like `portal.log` for the active log because there is some monitoring running on those log files. But I have not yet found out how that is possible. I guess Windows is causing some trouble here, too...